# Issue loading Main class from shell script Java

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-8, executable-jar

I want to invoke a Main class from jar file - Report.jar
There are 2 classes with main method in the jar file and both class in the same package - com.job

I am using below command from .csh to invoke main class

pathtojavabin/java -Xmx1024m -cp /pathToJarFile/Report.jar com.job.MainClass2

But its giving me error -
cannot find or load com.job.MainClass2

I am unable to understand where i am making mistake.

Comment: You can check that your jar is valid and contains the class file you expect by opening it as a zip. On linux use `unzip -l /pathToJarFile/Report.jar`, on windows rename it into `/pathToJarFile/Report.zip` then open it from the file explorer

Comment: @Aaron yes i did that and i can see .class file in jar - BOOT-INF/classes/com.job.MainClass2.class

Comment: the path inside the jar is weird. I'd have expected com/job/MainClass2.class. How did you package your jar?

Comment: Ah, is it a Spring Boot application ? If so, I think you're supposed to run it using java -Xmx1024m -jar /pathToJarFile/Report.jar

Comment: Yeah its a spring boot application. Incase of -jar how can specify which MainClass to invoke since i cannot change Manifest file to mention exact main class, because the same jar is used from other script and there i have used -jar which is working fine as MainClass1 is mentioned in manifest file.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Spring Boot apps, but I think it's in the application configuration/code that this should be set up, rather than as a command line option. Maybe an application.properties, or something like that?

Comment: Please post the result of `unzip -l /pathToJarFile/Report.jar | grep MainClass2` or `jar tf /pathToJarFile/Report.jar | grep MainClass2`

Comment: @g00se 
BOOT-INF/classes/com/job/MainClass2.class

Comment: That's not going to load. It would have to be `com/job/MainClass2.class`

Comment: @g00se it's a spring boot app, it looks like that's how application classes are packaged inside it ([source](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/executable-jar.html#appendix.executable-jar.nested-jars.jar-structure))

Comment: `pathtojavabin/java -Xmx1024m -cp /pathToJarFile/Report.jar -Xbootclasspath/a:BOOT-INF/classes com.job.MainClass2`

Comment: @Aaron Yes, I guessed so. The above should be a workaround

Comment: @g00se it did not work.. got same error

Answer (score 0):

Below worked for me,

pathtojavabin/java -Xmx1024m -cp /pathToJarFile/Report.jar -Dloader=com.job.MainClass2 org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).